# JavaScript Regex for capitalized letters with accents

Tags: javascript, regex

In JavaScript, its easy to match **letters and accents** with this regex:

```
text.match(/[a-z\u00E0-\u00FC]+/i);
```

And only the **lowercase letters and accents** without the `i` option:

```
text.match(/[a-z\u00E0-\u00FC]+/);
```

But what is the correct regular expression to match **only capitalized letters and accents**?

**EDIT:** like the answers already mention below, the regex above also matches some other signs, and miss some special accent characters like ý and Ý, ć and Ć and many others.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The range `U+00C0` - `U+00DC` should be the uppercase equivalent for `U+00E0` - `U+00FC`

So this `text.match(/[A-Z\u00C0-\u00DC]+/);` should be what you are looking for.

A site like [graphemica](http://graphemica.com/) can help you to determine the ranges you need yourself.

**EDIT**  like the other answers already mention, this also matches some other signs.

Comment: Thanks for the 3 good answers! It was difficult to chose on which one I'll click the accept button, so I choose the first answer. Also thanks t-niese and @confusion for the links, very helpful!

Answer (score 5):

Replace `a-z` with `A-Z` and `\u00E0-\u00FC` with `\u00C0-\u00DC` to *match the same letters* in uppercase as `text.match(/[a-z\u00E0-\u00FC]+/);` matches in lowercase.

**However**!
This is not a proper implementation, neither for lowercase nor for uppercase letters, as, for example, your lowercase match includes `÷` (division sign), which is not at all a letter, and my uppercase string will match `×` (multiplication sign), which looks like an X, but isn't actually a letter either.
In addition to that, you're missing characters like `ý` and `Ý`, `ć` and `Ć` and many, many others.

Answer (score 3):

Your first regex doesn't actually match letters and accents: it only matches letters and a specific subset of accented letters, namely the ones between unicode codepoints `\u00E0` and `\u00FC`. This range does not include any capital letters, while it does include e.g. the ÷ sign and some letters not generally regarded as 'accented'.

Depending on what you actually need, this may not be what you want. If you really want to match all capitals letters and all capital letters with the same accents, you need the regex `/[A-Z\u00C0-\u00DC]+/`, but please check with e.g. http://unicode-table.com/en/#basic-latin to check whether it suits your needs.

Comment: It does not include the % sign, that's `\u0025`. Don't mix up `%` and `÷`.

Comment: Yes, corrected. I was figuring out how to get SO to display that character :)

Answer (score 1):

To match all capitalized letters, accented or not, you may use the following unicode regex `/\p{Lu}+/u`. For example, in node repl:

[image]

Note that this will match non-latin letters as well, like the capital greek delta Δ in the example.